# trim value till specified string in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, trim

i want to trim value of the given string till specified string in oracle pl/sql.
some thing like below.

OyeBuddy$$flex-Flex_Image_Rotator-1443680885520.

In the above string i want to trim till $$ so that i will get "flex-Flex_Image_Rotator-1443680885520".

Answer (score 1):

You can use different ways; here are two methods, with and without regexp:

```
with test(string) as ( select 'OyeBuddy$$flex-Flex_Image_Rotator-1443680885520.' from dual)
select regexp_replace(string, '(.*)(\$\$)(.*)', '\3')
  from test
union all
select substr(string, instr(string, '$$') + length('$$'))
  from test
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do a `SUBSTR` where the starting position is going to be the position of `'$$' + 2` . `+2` is because the string `'$$'` is of length 2, and we don't want to include that string in the result.

Something like -

```
SELECT SUBSTR (
          'ABCDEF$$some_big_text',
          INSTR ('ABCDEF$$some_big_text', '$$') + 2)
  FROM DUAL;
```